# Versioning docx file in Subversion

Tags: xml, svn, version-control, ms-word, docx

I am wondering whether there is a method for versioning Word 2007/2010 files in subversion in the way that I can compare and blame?

I have discovered that the file could be saved as XML and then opened as normal docx file. However it is not beautified XML file, which makes it a little difficult to browse for diff and blame.

**Question**: What is the best approach for versioning MS Word documents in SVN?

Comment: I'm not sure about a way to deal with this in SVN but have you looked at Sharepoint?

Comment: I've also been known to store Word documents in various source control systems, but they're really not the best tool for the job. The XML may be semi-readable, but it's mainly intended for a computer to read.  Sharepoint is one good solution.  Turning on Track Changes as Oded suggests is also good if Sharepoint isn't an option.

Comment: Legal blackline, Compare and Track Changes are all built-in ways to compare Word documents. Why SVN? - that seems like overkill

Comment: @Duffman - Sharepoint is very expensive to buy if they aren't already using it.  Even with it, can't you only see previous version and doesn't have the diff functionality that the OP is looking for?

Comment: Dear God, someone suggested Sharepoint...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with using the built in [revisions tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/track-changes-in-word-197ba630-0f5f-4a8e-9a77-3712475e806a), aka "Track Changes"?

It is part of word, you will just need to store the different versions in source control, the revision tracking should give you your "blame".

Comment: the links are not available any more, can you please update them, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

THe answer for this questions is actually here: http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-03/1473.shtml

> Apply an svn:mime-type of application/msword to all your Word files as
>   an extra precaution.  If you use TortoiseSVN, it comes with a script
>   which will let you view  the differences between 2 versions using
>   Word's built-in capabilities.

And, very similar to this other question: [Is version control (ie. Subversion) applicable in document tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810/is-version-control-ie-subversion-applicable-in-document-tracking)