# Any way to merge documents with mercurial but never attempt to resolve conflicts?

Tags: merge, mercurial, ms-word

This is a followon question to:

[svn or mercurial version control of word documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374469/svn-or-mercurial-version-control-of-word-documents)

Since mercurial has the ability to process zipped files, it might be able to handle word docs.
But if it embeds change text, word is going to blow up.

In mercurial, is there any way to either merge a file, or report that it needs to be manually merged without actually getting the file and injecting bad characters in it?

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess all you need to do is to [set up an interactive merge tool](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeProgram#Configuring_a_merge_program). If this does not work, have a look at [merge patterns](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#merge-patterns).