# svn to store documents for the purpose of change management

Tags: svn, change-management, document-storage

Is it a good idea to keep project related documents in svn ? is there any document management app (sharepoint?) you can recommend for this ? The question is for a medium size software house (20 devs).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810/is-version-control-ie-subversion-applicable-in-document-tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a good idea to store your documents in a revision control system so that you can track the documents and keep revisions.

Comment: do you think it is the best approach to keep them together with source code or have a separate repository for the docs ?

Comment: Keep a separate repository for the docs. That assures you less hassle while checking out projects into Integrated Development Environments(IDEs) and product version management.

Comment: ... and repository maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need a document management app.  Users can go directly to http://svnserver/repository/trunk/project_a/doc1.doc or what have you.  The windows file open dialog can browse the repository as well.

I use Subversion but for sharing some documents and being able to edit the same document simultaneously I prefer google docs.

Answer (score 0):

We add an audit issue regarding versioning of word documents in SVN, where it is dificult to trace a specific version sent to the client to the correct version in the repository, meaning that there is not an easy way to use the version given by SVN to include in the cover sheet of the document itself, because the version of the file in SVN is impossible to know before commit. We have to use tags which is cumbursome to use.